# No hot water and low pressure

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure, plumbing-fixture

I have a Moen Banbury faucet in my bathroom. Over the last month or so I have noticed both reduced water pressure and no hot water. When I turn the hot handle, the water flow doesn't change all that much.

All supply lines in the basement are in good order and valves are open (the hot supply run also supplies our kitchen faucet with no issue).

What could be causing the issue?

If I turn on just the hot it is low pressure and cool.

Comment: if you turn on just the hot does anything come out?

Comment: I would replace the "cartridge" in the hot side.

Comment: Call MOEN and tell them the problem you are having. They can tell you how to fix the problem and send replacement parts usually for free. I have MOEN faucets and have never paid for any repair parts.

Answer (score 1):

If you live in a hard water area or have galvanized pipes try this:

1. Turn off the water supply at sink stops
2. Remove the handle and the nut that holds the cartridge
3. Pull the cartridge and make sure to not lose the parts
4. Clean the cartridge
5. With hand over the valve top, slowly crack open water to flush
6. Put it all back together
7. Repeat on the other side

I have found everything from rust, pebbles, pipe thread tape, and sand in valve stems since the orifices are so small they clog easily. I hope that is it. Good luck. ☺

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was replace the aerator insert. It was gummed up and the aeration mixed with the softened water was cooling the tap water. Now despite my tank less water heater it heats up much faster.